# Can't run multiple android emulator concurrently after update

Tags: android, android-emulator

Before installing updates in SDK Manager, it worked well. But then I cannot run two emulator at the same time. Any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem i have faced.

To solve this i have created new AVD and try to run this.

**OR**     `emulator-arm -avd <AVD>`

Now i am also able to run old AVDs

It has solved my problem. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've solved my problem..I open the second emulator by using command prompt...emulator-arm -avd <AVD>...thanks anyway..