# second android emulator instance isn't shown

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am trying to start 2 android emulator instance with avd's phone1 and phone2 respectively
when i can start both of them separately but never both of them at the same time.

the first one starts correctly but when i start the second one:
the avd manager gui shows the launch progress bar as usual, gives me back no error but won't show the second emulator instance.
 
according to the taskmanager there is indeed a second process (but the first one takes for example 400 mb ram and the second one only 15 )

what i've tried so far:
*starting them in a different order (so first phone2 then phone1)
*starting them from the command line using `emulator -avd phone1` and `emulator -avd phone2`
*tried having one emulator run an intel-x86 system image (of an other android os version) and having the other run an arm system image
*searching on the Android dev site (namely http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)
*searching on google and this site

useful info:
* i have the latest (at the moment of writing) revision of the android ask tools(20) and android sdk platform tools(12)
* i'm trying to run android 4.1
 both avd's have the same settings (but i've also tried with different ones)
* i have enough ram for both virtual machines

any help would be greatly appreciated !

tnx in advance !

EDIT answer was here: [Can't run multiple android emulator concurrently after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313980/cant-run-multiple-android-emulator-concurrently-after-update/11314092#11314092) 
(i searched this site with the keyword two instead of multiple so i didn't see this question)
 
use `emulator-arm -avd phone2` instead of `emulator -avd phone2` for the second one and it will work

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11314092/1289716

Comment: ok this was fast :p; tnx a lot it helped. i had tried searching this site but not with the keyword multiple. the solution is to start the second instance using emulator-arm instead emulator

Comment: you should appreciate that answer by upvote...

Comment: already did (the question and the comment with the answer in it)

Comment: @Andrew Aylett yes it is a duplicate, hadn't seen it

Comment: @Danny: the server puts a comment like that in when someone votes to close as duplicate -- I didn't type it myself!

Comment: @Andrew Aylett sorry i didn't know :)